# Django convert image to webp

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, webp

I have service in my Django project's app, that upload images, and I need to convert all images to webp to optimize further work with these files on the frontend side.

Draft of `_convert_to_webp` method:

```py
# imports
from pathlib import Path

from django.core.files import temp as tempfile
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
from PIL import Image


# some service class
...
    def _convert_to_webp(self, f_object: InMemoryUploadedFile):
        new_file_name = str(Path(f_object._name).with_suffix('.webp'))
        
        temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.temp.webp')
        # FIXME: on other OS may cause FileNotFoundError
        with open(temp_file 'wb') as f:
            for line in f_object.file.readlines():
                ... # will it works good?
        new_file = ...
        
        new_f_object = InMemoryUploadedFile(
            new_file,
            f_object.field_name,
            new_file_name,
            f_object.content_type,
            f_object.size,
            f_object.charset,
            f_object.content_type_extra
        )
        
        return new_file_name, new_f_object
...
```

`f_object` is `InMemoryUploadedFile` instance from POST request body (Django automatically create it).

My idea is to create a temporary file, write data from `f_object.file.readlines()` to it, open this file with `PIL.Image.open` and save with `format="webp"`. Is this idea a good one or there is another way to make file converting?

Comment: Upd: this new file is not needed for further work on server (that is why I use tempfile). After model instance create and save,  file will actually be uploaded to remote storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a pretty clean way to do this using the [django-resized](https://github.com/un1t/django-resized) package.

After pip installing, I just needed to swap out the `imageField` for a `ResizedImageField`

```py
    img = ResizedImageField(force_format="WEBP", quality=75, upload_to="post_imgs/")
```

All image uploads are automatically converted to .webp!

Comment: Looks much better, then my solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was pretty simple. `PIL.Image` can be opened using file instance, so I just opened it using `f_object.file` and then saved it in BytesIO instance with optimization and compression.

Correctly working code:

```py
# imports
from pathlib import Path

from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
from PIL import Image


# some service class
...
    def _convert_to_webp(self, f_object: InMemoryUploadedFile):
        suffix = Path(f_object._name).suffix
        if suffix == ".webp":
            return f_object._name, f_object
        
        new_file_name = str(Path(f_object._name).with_suffix('.webp'))
        image = Image.open(f_object.file)
        thumb_io = io.BytesIO()
        image.save(thumb_io, 'webp', optimize=True, quality=95)
    
        new_f_object = InMemoryUploadedFile(
            thumb_io,
            f_object.field_name,
            new_file_name,
            f_object.content_type,
            f_object.size,
            f_object.charset,
            f_object.content_type_extra
        )
        
        return new_file_name, new_f_object
```

`95%` was chosen as balanced parameter. There was very bad quality with `quality=80` or `quality=90`.